# Как получить переменную класса из делегата, передаваемого в этот класс?

Tags: c#, классы, делегаты

Имеется класс A, в котором объявлена переменные k,k2,kn. Надо передать в этот класс делегат с кодом, взаимодействующим с переменными класса А.
Для этого используется класс B. Проблема - из кода делегата внутри класса B не видно переменные класса A, и передать такой код в класс нельзя. Как решить, если решить вообще возможно?

```
class A
{
    public int k;
    public int k2;
    ...
    public in kn;
    public delegate void Delegate1();
    private Delegate1 Delegate;
    public A(Delegate1 GiveDelegate)
    {
        this.Delegate = GiveDelegate;
        this.Delegate();
    }
}
class B
{
    // код класса B
    public void interactWithA(int GiveInt)
    {
        A Test = new A(delegate(){ k = GiveInt; //множество действий с переменными });
    }
    // код класса B
}
```

Comment: Я бы создал событие в классе `B` и передавал класс `B`  в конструктор класса `A`. А у ж в классе `А` подписывался делегатом на событие класса `B`. Если уж так необходимы делегаты. Или использовать метод `public void SetK(int newK){k=newK;}`

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик,чуть-чуть подправил вопрос, к сожалению эти варианты не подходят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете, например, передать эту переменную как входной параметр.

```
class A
{
    int k;
    public delegate void UpdateIntDelegate(ref int n);
    UpdateIntDelegate updater;
    public A(UpdateIntDelegate updater)
    {
        this.updater = updater;
        this.updater(ref k);
    }
}
class B
{
    public B(int v)
    {
        A a = new A((ref int k) => k = v);
    }
}
```

---

**Дополнение**

Если вам почему-то нужно много отдельных переменных, вы можете точно так же передать их все отдельными параметрами. Но большое количество полей в классе означает скорее всего проблемы с дизайном.

Возможно, вам реально нужен *массив* данных, тогда вы можете передавать массив на вход делегату вместо одного числа.

Решения с открытием доступа на запись к полям скорее всего нарушают инкапсуляцию, так что я не рекомендовал бы этот путь.

Comment: мож тогда сразу весь объект `A` передавать?

Comment: @Grundy: Не, у объекта `A` поле может быть (то есть, _должно_ быть) приватным.

Comment: В данном случае только одна переменная. В реальном варианты их гораздо больше.

Comment: @VladD, ну это ж решается какими-нить протектед-интернал сеттерами

Comment: @Rubikoid: Тогда сформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы было наперёд понятно, какая у вас реальная задача.

Comment: @Grundy: То есть, намеренным нарушением инкапсуляции? Не, чё-то мне не нравится такой ход.

Comment: @VladD, не нарушением, а _расширением_ :-) так сказать сделать `B` другом `A`

Comment: @Grundy: (1) friend и есть нарушение инкапсуляции, (2) слава богу, в C# его нет. :)